# Is there a Hamiltonian system composed by three particles which is chaotic?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, chaos-theory

The Henon-Heiles system is the smallest Hamiltonian system where chaos has been observed. Smallest because it is composed by two degrees of freedom.

**What is a Hamiltonian system with $n=3$ degrees of freedom which shows chaos?**

*Just to avoid confusion, with chaos in Hamiltonian system, it is meant that above a certain energy threshold, there exist some trajectory which are unstable, i.e., the distance between two initially nearby trajectories will grow exponentially along the Hamiltonian flow*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem

Comment: Probably, I have not been precise. I meant a problem with three degrees of freedom.  In this case, I would have 9 spatial degrees of freedom. If I constrained the system to lie on a line maybe it would be "non-physical"?!

Comment: http://depts.washington.edu/amath/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/leah_ganis_pres.pdf

Comment: I just wonder what is the motivation for this curiosity

Comment: The Henon-Heiles system as well as other low dimensional Hamiltonian systems can be used for testing alternative approaches to this topic, for example, the geometric one. See the works made by W. Gibbons on the Jacobi metric for instance. Now, with a low dimensional system one can also employ semi-analytical approaches to address the problem of chaos. There is a motivation behind every question...

Comment: Thanks!........

Answer (score 2):

Triple pendulum would be an example of a chaotic system with three degrees of freedom (as well as double pendulum, which you can read on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum). The Hamiltonian would be pretty complex, though. Another, similar example of a Hamiltonian with chaotic behaviour can be, for instance, a Hamiltonian of two identical pendulums, connected by a rubber band
$$
H=\cos(\theta_1)+\cos(\theta_2)-\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)+\frac12(p_1^2+p_2^2).
$$

Comment: Thanks @Pavlo. B.. However, I actually see two spatial degrees of freedom, namely, $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$. Moreover, the Hamiltonian contains momenta instead of generalized velocities. Please, could you better explain that or alternatively provide another example?!

Comment: Yes, thanks for noticing the time derivatives. These should be momentums. 

Not sure about your concern with two/three variables. You can say that your Hamiltonian has a third, "dummy degree of freedom", $\theta_3$. Or, if you want to include the third variable in a non-trivial way, you can add a term $\cos \theta_3 - \cos (\theta_2-\theta_3)+0.5p_3^2$ to the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Yes, I agree that I could add a further variable so to reach the desired number of degrees of freedom. I would have been interesting to have a Hamiltonian system which was already widely studied where everything (or almost everything) was already known. 
Thanks for the suggestion!